# Why do i keep getting InvalidCast even though GetDouble returns a double

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sqlclient

In a C# program with .NET framework to make a windows form I have added the following code to make a connection and to get the value of result and store in a list for later usage

```
public List<Info> GetInfo(string Col)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=VIS-12\\TESTSQLSERVER;Database=SPCC;User Id=sa;Password=admin1234;";
            string comand = $"select {Col} from Tbl_Reading where [LogTime] between '2017-07-06 14:30:26.000' and '2017-07-06 14:30:26.000' ";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                double[] val1 = new double [100] ;
                conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand c1 = new SqlCommand(comand, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = c1.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    int x = 0;
                    val1[x] = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetDouble(0)); //this line is throwing the error 
                    x++;
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            List<Info> d1 = new List<Info>();
            d1 = (List<Info>)val1.Cast<Info>();//ToList();
            conn.Close();
            return d1;
            //return val1;
        }
    }
```

I still keep getting an invalid cast Exception even though the return type and the variable type is same

Comment: Which line in the code throw the exception?

Comment: Your Array is defined as a `double` … `double[] val1 = new double [100];` … A `double` isn’t going to know how to cast itself to an `Info` object. ... `val1.Cast<Info>` ...  Are wanting to use an array or list of `Info` objects when reading the data from the DB. `Info[] Val1 = new Info[100];` … or … `List<Info> val1 = new List<Info>();`

Comment: Not related to your question, but you will write all the values to val1[0]. Move  the `int x = 0;` out of the `while` loop; or - even better - use a `List<double>` and `Add`.

Comment: All the comments above are correct but if you really have the exception at the line signed then your first col in the _col_ variable is not a double. By the way, the Sql Injection problems is another factor to consider here.

Comment: It seems your code won't even compile, as you're trying to access `val1` outside its scope.

Answer (score 1):

`GetDouble` does indeed return type `double` but there has to be a `double` value to get. Internally, that method will get an `object` reference from the specified column and cast it as type `double`. It is that cast that is invalid, not one that you're performing. If you look at the stack trace of the exception then you should be able to see that.

Either the column you're retrieving is the wrong data type or at least one row contains NULL in that column. If the data type is correct then you need to either filter out NULL values in your query or else account for them in your reading code.

Answer (score 0):

`GetDouble` will throw an exception if the value internally is not a `double`. This will happen obviously if the column is a different type, but also if the value is a null. So you need to handle that case.

Other notes:

- `if (reader.HasRows)` is not necessary as you can use `reader.Read()` to tell you the same thing.
- Use a multi-line string with `@` to make your query more readable.
- I hope `Col` is not coming from user-input, otherwise you have a major injection vulnerability.
- You are missing `using` blocks to dispose your objects.
- There seems to be no need for the array, just convert each value as you go along and insert into a list.
- `between` doesn't seem to make sense here, also you should probably use a parameter for the date. If there is really a start and end time, use `>= AND <` rather than `BETWEEN`.
- Consider putting the connection string in a settings file, rather than hard-coding it.

```cs
public List<Info> GetInfo(string Col)
{
    string connectionString = "Server=VIS-12\\TESTSQLSERVER;Database=SPCC;User Id=sa;Password=admin1234;";
    string comand = @$"
select {Col}
from Tbl_Reading
where LogTime = @time;
";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand c1 = new SqlCommand(comand, conn))
{
    c1.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse("2017-07-06 14:30:26.000");
    List<Info> d1 = new List<Info>();
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = c1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            d1.Add((reader[0] as double) as Info);
        }
        return d1;
    }
}
```